# Kafka Source Connector : timestamp.delay.interval.ms not adding delay

Tags: apache-kafka, timestamp, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka source connector to read records from Oracle DB to topic .

My configuration is as below :

```
    "connection.password": "*******",
    "tasks.max": 2,
    "connection.user": "*****",
    "connection.url": "************",
    "mode": "timestamp",
   "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "query": "SELECT INSERT_DATE, COL2 FROM TABLE1",
        "key.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable" : "false",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable" : "false",
        
        "poll.interval.ms" : "60000",
        "timestamp.column.name": "INSERT_DATE",
        "topic.prefix": "myTopic",
        "max.retries":"0",
        "retry.backoff.ms":"300000",
        "numeric.mapping":"best_fit",
        "transforms": ",InsertField",
        "transforms.InsertField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
        "transforms.InsertField.static.field": "eventKey",
        "transforms.InsertField.static.value": "COL2",
        "timestamp.delay.interval.ms" : "120000"
```

What i want is : when record is updated into DB . after 120000 milliseconds ( 2 minutes ) i want kafka to read it and push to topic.

My DB INSERT_DATE is in UTC-5 format ( EST time )
I tried db.timeZone : US/Eastern  / UTC-5 - did not work

Can you let me know what i am missing here ?

DB is oracle

Edited : My question is : Kafka connect source connector is not adding delay. When the DB rec is inserted or updated , kafka is reading the record and pushing into topic. I want record to be read after 2 mins and not immediately .

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify exactly *what* is not working? Are you not getting records? Are you getting records but not after the expected delay?

Comment: I have edited the post with my question. Let me know if you need more info .

Comment: What value are you specifying for `mode` in your configuration?

Comment: "mode": "timestamp", . What i notice is because poll is 60000  , record is pushed to topic after 60000 ms . its not adding delay of 2 mins .

Comment: Is this on subsequent polls, or on the first one? Per the docs all records are grabbed on the first ingest

Comment: Which version of the connector are you running?

Comment: 2.5.0 - version of kafka connector

Comment: Is this on subsequent polls, or on the first one  -   I notice always its loading after poll interval . ( irrespective of 1st or subsequent polls )